# How I can forward port throught OpenVPN correctly?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding, openvpn

I'm trying to forward a port through OpenVPN (with Ethernet Bridging) but I can't.

Below is a "simple" network diagram. A server contains 2 virtual machines, the principal server is connected with OpenVPN to another server. I need forward a port from `10.10.10.2` (a Virtual Machine) to public IP of the external server with IP `10.10.10.11` (see diagram).

The bridge `vmbr0` is including a three interfaces: `tap0`, `eth0` (public IP) and `vlan1` (`10.10.10.0/24`).

[image: network diagram]

The rule I used in 10.10.10.11 server is

> iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp -d [public ip here] --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:80

In the image below you can see that packets "enter" but not "exit" through the interface `tap0`.

This is a dump of `tap0` interface:

[image: principal server]

The packets are entering correctly from `tap0`, but packets are routed to `vmbr0` and never get to `tap0`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Port forwarding this way doesn’t work like you expect it to: Incoming it’s A -> B -> C, but outgoing it’s C -> A, because it’s reachable directly. However, A expects a response from B.

Comment: Also, please provide the port forwarding rule as you added it via `iptables`(?).

Comment: The rule added to iptables is `iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp -d [public ip here] --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:80`

Comment: If you're ethernet bridging there shouldnt be any need to fwd...?

Comment: I need to be accessible from the public ip of the server 10.10.10.11

Comment: Which machine hosts the VPN (10.10.10.2 ?), and where did you add the DNAT rule ?    What happens if you ping/traceroute to the public IP from the source system, and where are the routers in your picture ?   (It might be useful if you updated your image to show where the router is as well)

Answer (score 0):

Bridges essentially turn a number of NICs into a virtual switch.

If you want devices to talk across a bridge, they need to be on the same subnet, as they would on a real switch.  If they are not on the same subnet, you need a router, not a switch or bridge.

So bridging your public IP `eth0` and `tap0` or `vlan1` NICs won't work unless you have 2 public IPs from your ISP - allowing you to put both of them on the same subnet.

You can put both your virtual machines on a bridge - and they can talk since they'll be on the same subnet.

Your system then needs to route and do NAT, using `eth0` as the "WAN" NIC and `vmbr0` as the "LAN" NIC.  Any guide you find on doing `iptables` with NAT can be used, just substitute `vmbr0` for `eth1` or the LAN-facing NIC.